# How to use a t-test to determine the best values from a set of scores

Tags: t-test

The scores are $R^2$ values of around 20 machine learning classifiers. Which of the scipy statistical tests methods would be appropriate here? (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statistical-tests) I'd like to see the best scores, for example, "according to a t-test with p <.05". For example, the classifier results might look like this:

| Classifier | Score |
| --- | --- |
| RF | 0.42 |
| MLR | 0.12 |
| ANN | 0.71 |
| SVR | 0.72 |
| ... | ... |

The best scores according to a t-test with p <.05 might be something like "0.71" and "0.72".

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What makes you see a t-test as appropriate for your task? I don’t see it but am open to learning. // Perhaps you can expand on what exactly you’re doing. For instance, depending on how you calculate $R^2$, you might not be shielding against overfitting the training data. (And if you’re a Python user, you’re probably even calculating $R^2$ with a function [with which I disagree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590199/247274), though that is less of a concern of mine right now.)

Comment: r2 are probably not enough, you will need target/prediction for each data point in the test set or at least sample size.