# multioutput='variance_weighted' in scikit-learn r2_score: what does it calculate?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, scikit-learn, r-squared

I am using scikit-learn r2_score function and I would like to understand what the option 'variance_weighted' calculates. In the documentation [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) it tells: *Scores of all outputs are averaged, weighted by the variances of each individual output*. Does it mean that the output is a weighted average whose weights are the variances of data of which score has to be calculated ?

For example:

```
>>> y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
>>> y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]
>>> r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='variance_weighted')
```

Here the variance for the first *individual output* means the variance of [0.5, 1, 0, 2] ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: the question has been answered from a computational point of view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937656/multioutput-variance-weighted-in-scikit-learn-r2-score-what-does-it-calculate) in StackOverflow. So it calculates the r2 score between each element corresponding to each axis, so in this case between [0.5,-1,7] and [0,-1,8], [1,1,-6] and [2,2,-5] and the variances, that represent the weights I was looking for, are the variances corresponding to the true values and so the variance of [0.5,-1,7] and of [1,1,-6].

At this point my doubt is: why do they weigh the r2 scores results using the variance of true values ? In this way, a higher variance in true values would lead to a higher importance of the r2 score value computed between such true values and the corresponding predicted values...

Comment: [Note that the utility of this function is debatable.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score)

Comment: @Dave I do not find other scores in my case so I would like to understand how this works.

Comment: [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109504/73930) Data Science post of mine could be of interest. The post for not directly address $R^2$ but does consider loss function for multivariate regression modes and how to combine the predictions made for each marginal distribution.