# Why is R^2 negative in my multiple linear regression model in python?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, linear-model

i want to evaluate the organization based on the number of satisfied customers
and the r^2 is negative
this is the original data

```
    SECTOR  price   profit  INSPECTION  licenses    PR  CS(S)   CS(NOT S)   A(s)    A (nonS)
0   A   3809    1643    6834.0  499.0   4053    203.0   45.0     NaN        NAN
1   B   18608   16270   6828.0  2815.0  10923   35.0    5.0      1980.0     200
2   C   3814    1861    2375.0  509.0   2107    99.0    43.0     NaN        NaN
3   A   15869   20293   2595.0  2206.0  5285    30.0    5.0      1150.0     NaN
4   B   5663    1881    3629.0  734.0   5667    220.0   55.0     NaN        565.0
```

and A(s) stands for the number of satisfied customers for the whole sectors meaning 200 include the services provided by sector A B and C

i foucused on sector B and does it affect A(s) or not

converted Sector so dummy and then deleted A and C sectors
this is what i have now

```
df1.corr()


price        profit     INSPECTION  licenses        PR       A(s)
CLEARANCE   1.000000    0.376304    0.211653    -0.044924   0.397780 0.389236
PERMITS     0.376304    1.000000    -0.021812   -0.158237   0.089504    0.373245
INSPECTION  0.211653    -0.021812   1.000000    0.573478    0.438797    0.245204
Facilities licenses     -0.044924   -0.158237   0.573478    1.000000    0.050931    -0.164353
PR  0.397780    0.089504    0.438797    0.050931    1.000000    0.497360
   

x = np.array(df1.drop(['A(s)'], axis=1))
y = df1['A(s)'].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

r2_score(regressor.predict(X_test), y_test)
```

the result of r^2
-0.6052320362843366
i do not know why the sign is negative
please help and thank you

Answer (score 2):

It means that your sum of squared residuals is greater than the sum of squared residuals of a model that always predicts the out-of-sample mean. This can be regarded as a baseline, “must beat” model. That you cannot achieve stronger performance than this baseline model means that your model is not doing a good job of predicting. While this might seem disappointing, you do out-of-sample testing to catch when you have such a model, so not all is lost.

[I dislike the `sklearn` implementation of out-of-sample $R^2$ and find it to lack motivation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) However, I would expect your training and testing means to be similar, so the $R^2$ you’ve reported is unlikely to differ much from what I would get from my preferred calculation.

Note that a linear regression, fitted using ordinary least squares, is guaranteed to have a non-negative in-sample $R^2$ as long as the model contains an intercept. Deviating from that situation, however, either because you use a nonlinear model, a linear model estimated by a method other than minimizing the sum of squared residuals, excluding an intercept, or measuring out-of-sample $R^2$, removes such a guarantee, as you have seen from your result.

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix this problem and should i use another model?

Comment: It’s a matter of the usual strategies for predictive modeling. Beyond that, your question is essentially asking how to do machine learning. Do you have a more specific question? If so, please consider posting a new question to ask.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a bug.

If you get negative r^2 on your test data (IIRC) with linear regression, it means your test data has a diff mean from your training data (or you are lacking an intercept).

sklearn defaults to using intercept.

Since you are doing a train test split and nothing else, you would not expect the data sets to differ.

I suspect that changing the random state to a non zero number might help.maybe 0 means that it doesn't shuffle the data and your data is ordered somehow?

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. It is fine to get $R^2<0$ on test data. That does not indicate a bug, just a poor model. This applies whether the out-of-sample data have the same mean as the in-sample data or not. // Just splitting the data randomly would cause the means of the train and test sets to be equal *in expected value*, yes, but not necessarily equal in any given split. (In fact, it would be quite surprising for the observed train and test means to be exactly equal.)

Comment: yes it is a "poor" model, because it cannot even fit the mean of the test data. *assuming* that the data is randomly split, this should not happen.  which is why I suggest a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by fitting the mean of the test data, and why do you have to be able to do this?