# Online r2 calculation does not match sklearn r2 calculation (python)

Tags: regression, python, regression-coefficients, linear, online-algorithms

I am trying to replicate sklearn's linear regression coefficients and r2 score with an online calculation (so that it updates with each additional point of data). Starting with this [code here](https://scaron.info/blog/simple-linear-regression-with-online-updates.html).

```
class SimpleLinearRegressor():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.dots = np.zeros(5)
        self.intercept = None
        self.slope = None
            
        self.tss = 0
        self.rss = 0
        self.r2 = 0
        
        self.count = 0
        self.y_sum = 0
        self.y_avg = 0

    def update(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
        
        self.dots += np.array(
            [
                x.shape[0],
                x.sum(),
                y.sum(),
                np.dot(x, x),
                np.dot(x, y),
            ]
        )
        size, sum_x, sum_y, sum_xx, sum_xy = self.dots
        det = size * sum_xx - sum_x ** 2
        
        self.count += 1
        self.y_sum += y
        self.y_avg = self.y_sum / self.count
        
        if det > 1e-10:  # determinant may be zero initially
            
            self.intercept = (sum_xx * sum_y - sum_xy * sum_x) / det
            self.slope = (sum_xy * size - sum_x * sum_y) / det
            
            self.tss += ((y - self.y_avg) ** 2).sum()
            
            resid = y - (self.intercept + (x * self.slope))
            self.rss += (resid ** 2).sum()
            self.r2 = 1 - (self.rss / self.tss)
```

So far the coefficients are spot on. However, the r2 calculation is consistently higher than sklearn's r2 calculation. Here is a comparison (calculating at each new point of the data):

[image: r2 scores not matching]

Here's the original data and table:

[image: line with slight noise]

[image: data]

```
0: line with some slight noise
score: sklearn r2 score
coef: sklearn coef
coef_incr: online coef
score_incr: online r2
```

Thank you

Comment: What is that y_avg variable? It’s an average of what?

Comment: It is the average of the true y variables (dependent variables).

Comment: Which true $y$ variables? The observations that trickle in?

Comment: yes, new true y variables

Comment: I’ve not yet figured out everything, but my discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) might lead you somewhere. I think it comes down to you and `sklearn` not quite agreeing on what $R^2$ should be. I’ll see what sense I can make out of this, and I hope to post an answer. (But if you figure it out, please do post a self-answer!)