# negative $R^2$ but positive correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared, negative-r-squared

I have a predictor $\hat{y}$. I have noticed that the correlation between $\hat{y}$ and $y$ are quite positive, above 50% even, while the $R^2$ is negative. Note that this is an out-of-sample $R^2$ and correlation. I train my predictor in-sample and test the correlation and $R^2$ out of sample.

Can someone explain what this say about my data?

Comment: $R^2$ cannot be negative. You'd better explain how you reached this conclusion that $R^2$ is negative.

Comment: It can be negative if you don't have constant or test out of sample?

Comment: I’ll gladly reopen if that doesn’t answer the question, and I will address follow-up questions in the comments. Still, I think the images in my linked answer are pretty compelling. // $R^2<0$ is possible in many situations, basically in any situation other than fitting a linear model with an intercept using ordinary least squares and calculating in-sample, if you calculate according to $1-SSRes/SSTotal$ (but not if you square the Pearson correlation).

Comment: $R^2=1-SSRes/SSTotal$  can be negative if your predictions are worse (in a mean square error sense) than using a constant $\bar y$.  This does not exclude positive correlation. If $y=(90,100,110)$ and $\hat y =(50,100,150)$ then $r=1$ but $R^2=-15$.  It will not happen with ordinary least squares regression, but can with other modelling or with out-of-sample prediction.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an out-of-sample $R^2$."

Comment: @Henry : Where in the world did you get $-15$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590199/247274 If you calculate in a way other than squaring the correlation between true and predicted values, it is possible to achieve a negative value.

Comment: Normally the notation $\widehat y$ would refer to a fitted value rather than a predictor.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I only see $\hat y$ being used to refer to fitted values here.

Comment: @Dave : The very first sentence calls $\hat y$ a predictor. Of course the correlation between the fitted values and the observed values will be positive, but that's different from saying the correlation between the predictor and the observed values is positive.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  $1-\frac{(90-50)^2+(100-100)^2+(110-150)^2}{(90-100)^2+(100-100)^2+(110-100)^2}=-15$

Comment: @Henry : If you mean $\hat y=(50,100,150)$ are predicted values and $y=(90,100,110)$ are observed values that were not used in making the prediction, then the expression you write is not an example of what I would have understood $\text{“}R^2\text{”}$ to mean.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am simply saying that in general a very poor model can produce negative $R^2$ values, while ordinary least squares regression will not.

Comment: @Henry : Note that I have posted this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/627589/definition-of-text-r2-text